# Accuracy of coordinates got from cell provider in Android app

Tags: android, coordinates

I have been working on an Android app where I want to get the coordinates of the current location using network provider. Can I know how feasible and accurate it is to get the coordiantes using the Network provider? Are there any other methods to get the coordinates to the android app? If yes please give me

Answer (score 0):

You can get Co-ordinates via GPS .

Comment: I dont want to use gps. So I opted for Network provider. How accurate is it to work on Network provider.

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/get-use-location-data-android-app-625012/